# Empty tags in xml to json conversion

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-grouping

Trying to populate the empty tags without disturbing the existing logic in xsl code.
only the parameters should be displayed in the Json file.

Need to populate the emptyp tags as per the expected json file.

```
Input xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:PO_Record
    xmlns:ns0="http://Test.com/Order">
    <domainId>TEST</domainId>
    <hubDomainId>TEST</hubDomainId>
    <isForReference>false</isForReference>
    <status>Ok</status>
    <docStatus>Success</docStatus>
    <editingStatus>confirmed</editingStatus>
    <vpoNo>10000341</vpoNo>
    <vpoDate>2021-03-05</vpoDate>
    <instructions></instructions>
    <businessRefNo>10000341</businessRefNo>
    <totalItems>0</totalItems>
    <totalQty>0</totalQty>
    <customFields>
        <customFieldDate1>2042-01-21</customFieldDate1>
    </customFields>
    <season>
        <code>F22</code>
    </season>
    <custId>
        <custCode>TEST</custCode>
        <refNo>002001</refNo>
    </custId>
    <vendorId>
        <vendorCode>1235</vendorCode>
    </vendorId>
    <vpoItemList></vpoItemList>
    <vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList></vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>    
    <vpoShipDtlCsGroupList></vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>
</ns0:PO_Record>
```

ExpectedJsonFile:
{ "domainId" : "TEST",
"hubDomainId" : "TEST",
"isForReference" : "false",
"status" : "Ok",
"docStatus" : "Success",
"editingStatus" : "confirmed",
"vpoNo" : "10000341",
"vpoDate" : "2021-03-05",
"instructions" : "",
"businessRefNo" : "10000341",
"totalItems" : "0",
"totalQty" : "0",
"customFields" :
{ "customFieldDate1" : "2042-01-21" },
"season" :
{ "code" : "F22" },
"custId" :
{ "custCode" : "TEST",
"refNo" : "002001" },
"vendorId" :
{ "vendorCode" : "1235" },
"vpoItemList" :
[
],
"vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList" :
[
],
"vpoShipDtlCsGroupList" :
[  ] }

```
xslt code:    
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                    expand-text="yes"
                    version="3.0">
                
                  <xsl:output method="text"/>
                
                  <xsl:template match="/">
                      <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
                          <xsl:apply-templates/>
                      </xsl:variable>
                      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
                  </xsl:template>
                  
                  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
                    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
                  </xsl:template>
                  
                  <xsl:template match="*[(*) and . castable as xs:double]">
                    <number key="{local-name()}">{.}</number>
                  </xsl:template>
                  
                   <xsl:template match="*[*]">
                    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:boolean" select="false()"/>
                    <map>
                      <xsl:if test="$key">
                        <xsl:attribute name="key" select="local-name()"/>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
                          <xsl:choose>
                              <xsl:when test="current-group()[2] or self::vpoItemList or self::vpoItemCsList or self::vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList or self::vpoShipDtlCsGroupList">
                                  <array key="{local-name()}">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                      <xsl:when test="self::vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList">
                                        <array>
                                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                                          </xsl:apply-templates>                        
                                        </array>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:when test="self::vpoShipDtlCsGroupList">
                                        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="itemLotNo">
                                          <array>
                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                                              <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                                          </array>
                                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                                      </xsl:when>
                                      <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                                          <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                                      </xsl:otherwise>                      
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                  </array>
                              </xsl:when>
                              <xsl:otherwise>
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="key" select="true()"/>
                                  </xsl:apply-templates>
                              </xsl:otherwise>
                          </xsl:choose>
                      </xsl:for-each-group>
                    </map>
                  </xsl:template>
                </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change that last template to check for empty groups/elements e.g.

```
              <xsl:template match="*[*]">
                <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:boolean" select="false()"/>
                <map>
                  <xsl:if test="$key">
                    <xsl:attribute name="key" select="local-name()"/>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
                      <xsl:choose>
                          <xsl:when test="not(current-group()[2]) and (self::vpoItemList or self::vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList or self::vpoShipDtlCsGroupList)">
                            <array key="{local-name()}"></array>
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:when test="current-group()[2] or self::vpoItemList or self::vpoItemCsList or self::vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList or self::vpoShipDtlCsGroupList">
                              <array key="{local-name()}">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                  <xsl:when test="self::vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList">
                                    <array>
                                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                                      </xsl:apply-templates>                        
                                    </array>
                                  </xsl:when>
                                  <xsl:when test="self::vpoShipDtlCsGroupList">
                                    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="itemLotNo">
                                      <array>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                                          <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                                      </array>
                                    </xsl:for-each-group>
                                  </xsl:when>
                                  <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                                      <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                                  </xsl:otherwise>                      
                                </xsl:choose>
                              </array>
                          </xsl:when>
                          <xsl:otherwise>
                              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                                <xsl:with-param name="key" select="true()"/>
                              </xsl:apply-templates>
                          </xsl:otherwise>
                      </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:for-each-group>
                </map>
              </xsl:template>
```

Comment: The code failed when we have the  <vpoItemList></vpoItemList>
    <vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList></vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList>    
    <vpoShipDtlCsGroupList></vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>

Comment: Which "code failed", the original one in your question or the one suggested in the answer? Anyway, try to show us well-formatted sample data and explain the rules for the transformation instead of dumping some unformatted snippets into comments or questions.

Comment: The original one in the question. It should populate the data when we have data in the xml nodes.   <vpoItemList>
  <itemNo>12345-2020-1002-45671</itemNo>
  <itemName>Wallace</itemName></vpoItemList><vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList><qty>5</qty><refNo>00001/12345-2020-1002-45671-1</refNo></vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList><vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>
  <itemLotNo>12345-2020-1002-45671-Lot1</itemLotNo>
  <shipmentNo>00001</shipmentNo> </vpoShipDtlCsGroupList>

Comment: Given in the new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69402496/empty-elements-in-the-xml-to-json-conversion

Comment: Hi Martin - The original scenario failed with the code changes...vpoItemList" : [ ], "vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList" : [ ], not populating when we have data in the nodes.

Comment: @raviteja, it is hard to patch that for any case you come up with, perhaps instead of the empty `<array key="{local-name()}"></array>` I put in there for the case of `test="not(current-group()[2]) and (self::vpoItemList or self::vpoShipDtlDtoGroupList or self::vpoShipDtlCsGroupList)"` you also want to populate the array using e.g. `<array><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"><xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/></xsl:apply-templates></array>` instead. But try to adapt the examples in the various answers to the variants of your input data in various questions to your needs.